# How to add two line in the same canvas in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

Hi I have a data frame with 3 columns

```
    number_of_episodes  mean_reward gamma
69995   69995   -19370.442404   0.100064
69996   69996   -19370.442404   0.100051
69997   69997   -19370.442404   0.100039
69998   69998   -19370.442404   0.100026
69999   69999   -19370.442404   0.100013
```

I use Plotly to plot the relationship between the `number_of_episodes` for each of the other two variables
I can use the `px.line` to plot each one separately like this

```
fig = px.line(df, x="number_of_episodes", y='mean_reward')
fig.show()

fig = px.line(df, x="number_of_episodes", y='gamma')
fig.show()
```

is there a way to plot both graphs in the same canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 4.8 of Plotly you can simply call:

```
fig = px.line(df, x="number_of_episodes", y=['mean_reward','gamma'])
fig.show()
```

https://community.plotly.com/t/announcing-plotly-py-4-8-plotly-express-support-for-wide-and-mixed-form-data-plus-a-pandas-backend/40048

Comment: I didn't notice that I used an old version of plotly that I need to upgrade THANK YOU